# Why Interlocked.CompareExchange is not working?

Tags: c#, interlocked

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.popcount, this.popcount + 1, this.popcount) == this.popcount)
{
    pop = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref head, head.next, head);
}
```

I write a code but somehow it's not working as I wanted...

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.popcount, this.popcount + 1, this.popcount)
```

I think this means

1. go to `this.popcount` reference and get value of popcount
2. compare value with `this.popcount`
3. if it is same, add 1 to `this.popcount`

Am I wrong? If I'm wrong, how can I correct it?

Comment: In what case would you expect the comparison between the value of `popcount` with itself to return false?

Comment: And since the result of `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is the old value of the `ref` parameter, when would you expect the comparison against the new value of `popcount` to return `true`?

Comment: Sorry I can’t understand... I think value from ref this.popcount and this.popcount should be always same. Because I don’t change the value of popcount. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember *the value that you added 1 to*, the "before" value, and cannot rely on (re-) reading it from the variable you're going to change. Because the whole point is that multiple threads are competing to update this variable's value. So you want something like:

```
var oldcount = this.popcount;
var newcount = oldcount + 1;

if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.popcount, newcount, oldcount) == oldcount)
{
    //It worked
}
else
{
    //Loop round, try again, whatever you plan to do when you don't succeed.
}
```

With your example, even if the `CompareExchange` succeeds, you're then comparing the old value (returned by `CompareExchange`) to the new value (that you freshly read via `this.popcount` to the right of `==`) and it's unlikely those will ever match. Conversely, they might be equal if your call to `CompareExchange` actually failed.

---

Of course, if you're just incrementing a variable, `Interlocked.Increment` would be more appropriate.